# Why the X is the symbol associated to the “Close application” action?

Tags: design-patterns, symbols

I was wondering about the reason of the choose of the X as symbol used to represents the "Close application" operation.

Comment: related to eXit ? (just wondering)

Comment: Possible related to - When you want to cross out something you've written, you draw an X over it.

Comment: Please avoid answering in comments. Try to find some support for your claims, and make them as full answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article **["The origins of the use of [x] in UI design"](https://medium.com/re-form/x-to-close-417936dfc0dc)** you can read:

> The use of [x] for close and [o] for open could come **from the Japanese symbols batsu and maru**.

[image: Bastsu and maru]

> **Batsu (x) is the symbol for incorrect**, and can represent false, bad, wrong or attack, while maru (o) means correct, true, good, whole, or something precious. Batsu and maru are also **common hand gestures**. Cross your arms over your chest for batsu, circle your arms over your head for maru.